# Why do RNNs use the crossentropy as a loss function

Tags: machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network, cross-entropy

I am very new to neural networks and was wondering why all of the examples of RNNs, especially char-rnns use the crossentropy loss function as their loss function. I have googled but can't seem to come across any discussions on the function in this context. I have been asked to motivate for its use and look at its advantages and disadvantages so any papers or sources that I could read through would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Many sequence-to-sequence RNNs, and [char-rnn](https://github.com/karpathy/char-rnn) in particular, produce the result by one item at a time, in other words by solving a *classification problem* at each time step.

Cross-entropy loss is the [main choice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36515202/712995) when doing a classification, no matter if it's a convolutional neural network ([example](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/convolutional_network_raw.py)), recurrent neural network ([example](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.py)) or an ordinary feed-forward neural network ([example](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/neural_network_raw.py)). If you were to write an RNN that solves a *regression problem*, you'd use a different loss function, such as L2 loss.

All of examples above are using [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) and `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` loss.