# tensorflow autoencoder is not learning in training

Tags: tensorflow, autoencoder

I am trying to generate synthetic data with tensorflow autoencoder that is very close to given original data. But, autoencoder is not learning in training phase. My cost function is not decreasing generally and synthetic data unrelated with original data. My code is given below:

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, COLUMN])
# Weights and biases to hidden layer
Wh = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((COLUMN, UNITS_OF_HIDDEN_LAYER), -1.0 / mpmath.sqrt(COLUMN), 1.0 / mpmath.sqrt(COLUMN)))
bh = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([UNITS_OF_HIDDEN_LAYER]))
h = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, Wh) + bh)
# Weights and biases to output layer
Wo = tf.transpose(Wh) # tied weights
bo = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([COLUMN]))
y = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h, Wo) + bo)

# Objective functions
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(x - y, 2))
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE).minimize(cross_entropy)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

train_number, _ = x_train.shape


for j in range(TRAINING_EPOCHS):
    sample = np.random.randint(train_number, size=BATCH_SIZE)
    batch_xs = x_train[sample][:]
    _, cost = sess.run([optimizer, cross_entropy], feed_dict={x: batch_xs})
    print("COST: ", cost)

encodedTensor = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(x_train, Wh), bh))
encodedData = sess.run(encodedTensor)

decodedTensor = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(encodedData, Wo), bo))
decodedData = sess.run(decodedTensor)
return decodedData
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried different weight initialization like

```
Wh = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_inputs,n_hiddens1],0,0.1),name='W1')
bh = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hiddens1],0,0.1),name='b1')
```

this works find for my code,further more maybe

```
 Wo = tf.transpose(Wh) # tied weight
```

Is not such a good idea because in the gradient descent tensorflow might see those as the same variable or dependent variable and modify them at every iteration of the optimization

anyway if you use tensorboard you will see if one of these two bug option is true

Answer (score 0):

Your loss function is MSE. It would be better if you switch to cross-entropy loss for auto-encoders. Here you can find a detailed information about it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515202/why-is-the-cross-entropy-method-preferred-over-mean-squared-error-in-what-cases).

Comment: could you please explain why? I thought that auto-encoders do regression, not classification

Comment: autoencoders can be used for regression as well as classififcation