# Predict the next outcome MLP neural network Python

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, anaconda, lstm

I am trying to predict the next set of numbers in my dataset sequence however using the predict function classifys the entire dataset, how can I change my code so that it predicts the next outcome in the sequence?

I was following this tutorial and his model outputs 80 based on 50,60,70 as his dataset. Yet mine just predicts the entire dataset? [How to Get Started with Deep Learning for Time Series Forecasting (7-Day Mini-Course)](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-get-started-with-deep-learning-for-time-series-forecasting-7-day-mini-course/)

This is my dataset

[image]

and this is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix

from numpy import loadtxt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
# load the dataset
col_names = ['N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4', 'N5', 'L1', 'L2','label']
# load dataset 
pima = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", header=None, names=col_names)
pima.head()

feature_cols = ['N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4', 'N5', 'L1', 'L2']
X = pima[feature_cols] # Features
y = pima.label 

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(122, input_dim=7, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=2000, batch_size=10)
# =======================
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(X, y)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))

yhat = model.predict(X, verbose=0)
print(yhat) <- this outputs the predictions for the entire dataset and not the next prediction
```

Edit:

The output I am getting is this, for the entire dataset.

[image]

The dataset runs from 1 to 1251 rows and I want to predict row 1252 with an output of N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,L1,L2.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by predicting the entire dataset? what is the shape of your output and etc?

Comment: I will post an edit with the output.

Answer (score 0):

You have sigmoid activation as your final layer, which gives outputs in range [-1, 1], which is not what you want for your final layer as you are predicting the next number.

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

try changing this to

```
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Also, you better use MSE loss function for this type of tasks, BCE is used more for classification tasks, you can check that here

[Why is the Cross Entropy method preferred over Mean Squared Error? In what cases does this doesn't hold up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515202/why-is-the-cross-entropy-method-preferred-over-mean-squared-error-in-what-cases)

```
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

hope this solves your problem

Comment: I dont think thats it, I have updated my question. The `model.predict` is outputting its predictions for the entire dataset as if its classifying and not actually predicting the next sequence of numbers?

Comment: Using your answer I also get this error `TypeError: '(0, slice(None, None, None))' is an invalid key`

Comment: I just said about input matrix vs vector, I will test the code now and get back to you

Comment: I understand, the dataset runs from 1 to 1251 rows and I want to predict row 1252 with an output of N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,L1,L2 however I cant figure out 1) why its classifying my entire dataset and 2) how to output a matrix like you said. I was assuming I need to figure out why number 1) is happening first?

Comment: Oo I see, sorry I didnt pay attention to that, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Its still classifying all of X? Its not predicting row 1252?

Comment: Can you give me some part of output?

Comment: `yhat = model.predict(X, verbose = 0)
print(yhat)
[[0.01997364]
 [0.10846496]
 [0.07146579]
 ...
 [0.45351756]
 [0.05341327]
 [0.20674002]]`

Comment: Did you remove sigmoid from the last layer?

Comment: The output of yhat prediction should be Row 1252 (or just one row): 2, 18, 26, 48, 50, 1, 11. It should not be classifying all of X which it seems to be doing? Yes I removed sigmoid.